# Android Getting Bound Object from OnClick

Tags: android

I'm totally stuck with something. I'm trying to do simple de-reference of a clicked object in Android environment but for the life of me can't find a way.

I have a MainView where I load json objects and I pass these objects to my adapter where I find these to a list. I have onClick on a TextView items in a list to capture click events.

Issue: the OnClick fires but I can't get back the original bound object from there, or I'm not sure how? I was trying to use a position variable that increments when getView function gets called for each row, but my position when OnClick happens always points to the last record in my list. I also tried implementing onItemClick in MainView but that never seems to fire.

How can I get back the object I bound to my TextView? Thank you in advance for any assistance with this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
private static final String LOCATION_KEY = "location";

SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public JSONObject jsonObj = null;
ListView mainList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.digitour.www.R.layout.activity_main);

    // Load state from shared preferences
    pref= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=pref.edit();`enter code here`
    mainList = (ListView) findViewById(com.digitour.www.R.id.checkableList);

    try {

       jsonObj=new JSONObject(pref.getString("json",null));

        // Bind Data and pass the json object read from a file to the adapter
        MainViewAdapter customListViewAdapter = new MainViewAdapter(this, jsonObj);
        mainList.setAdapter(customListViewAdapter);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here is the adapters code:

```
public class MainViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;
private JSONArray listItems;
private int positionPrivate;
private JSONObject jsonObj;

public MainViewAdapter(Context context, JSONObject jsonObj) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.jsonObj = jsonObj;

    JSONObject jObjectResult = null;

    try {
        jObjectResult = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Items");
        this.listItems = jObjectResult.getJSONArray("Item");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final SharedPreferences pref= context.getApplicationContext    ().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    try {
        positionPrivate = position;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate    (com.digitour.www.R.layout.activity_row,parent,false);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById    (com.digitour.www.R.id.rowText);
        textView.setText(listItems.getJSONObject(position).getString    ("description"));

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    //Trying to get here the bound object
                    TextView tv = (TextView)v;
                    int id = tv.getId();

                    if (listItems != null){
                        JSONObject clickedItem = listItems.getJSONObject(positionPrivate); // positionPrivate always indexed to last item in a list

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);

                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });

        return convertView;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single member variable `private int positionPrivate` that you store the index in.  It can only hold one index, so ends up with the last index that was written to it.

Try removing this variable and just use the `position` parameter in your `getView` function.

```
JSONObject clickedItem = listItems.getJSONObject(position);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that did it!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a `setTag(Object tag)` method.

```
textView.setTag(position)

textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (int) textView.getTag()

        if (listItems != null) {
            JSONObject clickedItem = listItems.getJSONObject(position);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was curious about the getTag() as I didn't use that function before. That approach works as well, I just had to add      "textView.setTag(listItems.getJSONObject(position).getString("id"));" in my getView method, otherwise I was getting null ref error. Thanks a lot.